# How to avoid calling scale_color_manual all the time

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plots with all the same values in `scale_color_manual`.
I want to avoid this and just call one time a function like this :
`theme(manual_colors = c("#000000", "#111111"))`

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this by masking `scale_colour_discrete`:

```
scale_colour_discrete <- function(...)  {

    scale_colour_manual(...,values=c("#000000","#111111"))
}
```